# Как вывести фразу на сайт?

Tags: javascript

Вот скрипт выводит фразу kod5 на странице через 5 секунд; проблема в следующем: надо чтобы выводилась фраза на сайте в определенной позиции. Сейчас фраза выводится на белом фоне,  стирая, обнуляя страницу; как поправить скрипт?

```
function sscroll()
{
    document.write("kod5");
}
var cmd = "sscroll()";
idTimer = window.setTimeout(cmd, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="info"></div>
...
idTimer = setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'kod5';}, 5000);
```

Comment: спасибо спасибо спасибо! я теперь фанат этого сайта! только вы смогли ответить мне на этот вопрос а задавал я его на 10 сайтах и форумах!

Comment: Ответили, но не объяснили, почему ваш код не работает как вы ожидаете. Если вызывать document.write() после загрузки страницы, то он затирает всё её содержимое. Лучше вообще этой функцией не пользоваться. 

И вместо 

> var cmd = "sscroll()";
> idTimer = window.setTimeout(cmd, 5000);

гораздо лучше писать

> var idTimer = setTimeout(sscroll, 5000);

Comment: http://alljs.ru/articles/document-write.html#errors - тут все сказано. В том числе и на счет "Лучше вообще этой функцией не пользоваться". "И вместо ... гораздо лучше писать ..." - а вы уверены, что переменная idTimer не определена раньше?

Comment: И что же там сказано, что противоречит тому, что я написал? :)

«а вы уверены, что переменная idTimer не определена раньше?» — попробуйте посмотреть внимательнее, это не единственное отличие.

А-а, вы (ling), наверное, решили, что я вам ответил. Что ж, бывает :)

Comment: А я и не противоречу - я дополняю). И ваш комментарий к моему ответу намекает, что вы писали мне. Что ж, попутал).

Answer (score 0):

[[@ling](/users/1252/ling)](/users/1252/ling) подсказал мне, как сделать, чтобы не "затиралась" страница. Я воспользовался его советом и у меня все получилось - огромное спасибо. Вот как я сделал (кусок HTML)

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="hello.js"></SCRIPT>
<div id="info">.</div>
```

и в файле hello.js

```
idTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'g5u9t1df8rh';
}, 125000);
```