# Действие OnClick в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Можно ли в javascript сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку на странице (без ее перезагрузки) выводилась, например, определенная для каждой кнопки статья. Например, если делать так

```
<input type="button" value="привет" name="a" OnClick="a();">
<input type="button" value="пока" name="b" OnClick="b();">
<input type="button" value="погода" name="c" OnClick="c();">
<input type="button" value="природа" name="d" OnClick="d();">

<script language="JavaScript">
function a()
{
    document.write('<p>привет</p>');
}
function b()
{
    document.write('<p>пока</p>');
}

function c()
{
    document.write('<p>погода</p>');
}

function d()
{
    document.write('<p>природа</p>');
}
</script>
```

то при нажатии на кнопку текст открывается в новом пустом окне.

Comment: Сходная задача уже решалась сегодня: http://hashcode.ru/questions/14653/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отлично, [Как вывести фразу на сайт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/14653/) - это то, что надо: теперь все работает

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
    function a()
    {document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'kod5';}
    function b()
    {document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'kod6';}        
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Hello!" name="hello" OnClick="a();">
<input type="button" value="Hello!" name="hello" OnClick="b();">
<div id="info"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Теперь при нажатии на кнопки выводятся различные статьи без перезагрузки страницы в этом же окне.

Answer (score -1):

Надо работать напрямую с DOM:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function hello()
{
    var p = document.createElement('p');

    document.body.appendChild(p);
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello!"));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Hello!" name="hello" onclick="hello();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит никакой текст (Hello!) не выводится